# for loop syntax with grep in bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, grep

I want to do text processing for lines in *file.txt* that ends with 0, I wrote an easy form of it to ask my question clearly.

```
$ cat file.txt
1 343 4352 0
324 4324 4324 324
432 432 2345 0

$ cat script.sh
for i in `grep " 0$" file.txt`
do
  echo $i; 
done
```

I want the output to be:

1 343 4352 0

432 432 2345 0

I want `$i` variable to be "1 343 4352 0" and after that to be "432 432 2345 0"
but in this script `$i` variable is valued 1 then 343

Comment: as per @AvinashRaj comment, there is no loop required here

Comment: thanks , but my script isn't this. this is the easy for of it to make my question clear, I need i variable to be the out put of grep to do sth with them. and also I want to learn how to do this with for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(grep ' 0$' file.txt))
for  i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  echo "$i"
  #do other tasks here.
done
```

Comment: Fair enough, I posted an alternative then with the caveat it's also probably not what the OP really should be doing at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly NOT the right way to do whatever it is you are trying to do but to answer the specific question you asked:

```
$ grep ' 0$' file |
while IFS= read -r i
do
    echo "$i"
done
1 343 4352 0
432 432 2345 0
```

If you are going to be doing text processing - do it in awk, not shell for simplicity, clarity, robusteness, performance, and every other desirable attribute of good software:

```
$ awk '/ 0$/ {i=$0; print i}' file
1 343 4352 0
432 432 2345 0
```

The above is just setting/using a variable to show how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bash built-in "REPLY"

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r ;do
    echo $REPLY ;done < file.txt
```

cheers Karim